# Open an email (for example, Hotmail or Gmail) inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, gmail

Well, I'm trying to open emails inside an iframe on my page, but then after a short time the frame vanishes and the email page appear.
I've read here on Stack Overflow that it's impossible to open, at least Gmail, on a frame, because of that framebuster that Google implemented.
Is that for real?=/

Do you know about an API, widget? I don't know, that is able to show my mailbox, compose a page or at least notify me of new emails on the entry folder?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Wish I could give you some words of wisdom but the framebuster works very well. I don't think that it is going to happen.

You *might* be able to have a PHP script that would be able to tell you if you have any new emails but that is out of my jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique to stop a frame from busting, read about it [here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/). However I believe it is possible to bust this frame-buster-buster, so it may not work.

In general though I would advise against something like this. It is hacky and if a site does not want to be framed you should respect this. If it has to work with only one site you may get any with it. But if it has to work with many I can guarantee it will introduce more problems. I strongly advise a different design pattern.

Incidently, according to [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/):

> Gmail supports the standard IMAP and
>   SMTP protocols for accessing and
>   sending e-mail messages

so you should really look at using this to provide the kind of functionality you are after.